# Get user permissions and post to wall from Desktop app?

Tags: php, barcode, offline, facebook-wall, rfid

I'm trying to ideate a facebook application where user would:

1- login to FB through the browser
2- accept the app's permissions (offline_access*, publish_stream, etc)

*Then we'll generate a barcode/rfid card where the main code will be his/her username/ID. When user puts his card under the reader, "the system" should launch something and post something to his wall/timeline*

**So:**

I guess I'll have to develop a separate desktop app that receives the code from reader and then to launch a browser with my app url plus some app_data?

Is there a way I could "login" user automatically to my FB app after card passed through the reader, by using some token or similar (knowing user accepted permissions previously)?

I'm throwing ideas, hope someone can share others so I can clear this on my mind

**Thanks**

Comment: "Once the migration setting has been enabled, Desktop applications will automatically get user access_tokens returned that have the longer expiration time. However, there is no way to get a long-lived user access_token without having the user login to your app again."

Comment: Check this if you want to know more https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: I assume that you already get user id. If you dont please tell me i can help with that too. Ater getting user id you can publish on user behalf to facebook using graph api with your application access token. Application access token is diffrent from user's active access token. Example graph api url is like "https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_USER_ID/feed?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&message=YOUR_MESSAGE". This can be sent by HTTP GET method. Detailed information can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: @bhdrkn Yes, I have used id. I get it after user approves the publish_stream permission. So, you say I can post to user wall without him being logged with graph api and application access token? Do you have an example? If so, I'd give u the +50 rep.

Comment: @Enriue sory to mislead you. In order to post messages, you must make request with http POST. I have an example, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Extended Access Token** (Long-lived Access Token)

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Store or update this in your database when user accesses your application
$extended_access_token = $facebook->getExtendedAccessToken();
```

Extended Access Token is valid for 60 days.

Comment: Hi Zany. I've tried this way but didn't work (i have latest sdk, etc.). I only could get the extended access token using this code: http://pastebin.com/wNsQFmXf

Comment: Now with extended access token, are you able to accomplish what you want?

Comment: Yes! tried it after 2 days, from an external page with QRCode, and worked! Now the main concern is to build something alternative just in case it stops working lol

Comment: Unfortunately, using extended access token is the only known way to do offline access. If "it stops working" refers to your application getting banned due to Facebook's policy, it is a risk you have to accept, there is no alternative.

If my answer is useful, do help to accept it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to acquire and store access token on step 1. With this token you can post on user' behalf. How to acquire a token is well described on facebook help page. Apparently there is no offline_access. You need a token with a long expiry date https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/.

Finally the worse bit. You want to post on user's behalf. If you are planning to post a FIX content I must warn you - **facebook will ban you**. They don't allow making up content for a user. It's consider as spam. What you can do is post an open graph action.

Comment: I know. Whatever I post, I will ask user permission before. I've done this with publish_stream before, but now my main concern is how to post on user wall without him being logued into FB. The idea is to ask permission, then make an rfid/qrcode/barcode card with user id. When he passes over reader -at other pc-, a wall post in his wall is made. Hope u've understood my english. Thanks

Comment: You should take his point on posting fixed content. If this goes high scale, Facebook will **DELETE** your app rightaway. You would be lucky if you even have it restricted.

Answer (score 0):

My Php skills are not well. But it think you can post using this script using HTTP post.

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&message=YOUR_MESSAGE';
$ch = curl_init($url);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This response contains a JSON object which holds post_id.